# How can you test/run pipeline scripts from the command line?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to run Jenkins Pipeline DSL scripts from the command line.

My use case is that I'm developing a large pipeline script which 'load's in other files, and at least one of the loaded files is trying to do an import.

Setting this all for quick iterative testing in the UI is very inefficient due to the number of clicks and copy/paste/etc.

So is there a way to run the scripts -- or at least to check the syntax of them -- from the command-line? Some series of import of libraries?

Comment: What kind of import are you talking about?

Comment: The pipeline script is loading in a groovy file.

The groovy file is doing an "import <libname>"

The <libname>  is then doing an "import" of another file with a class definition.  When <libname> tries to create an instance of that class, Jenkins is giving extremely unhelpful messages (which I don't have access to at the moment to post).

This is all pretty irritating to try to fiddle with in the UI, since multiple files are involved, and I'd love to be able to test it without having to actually run the jobs in Jenkins somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while it's not the pure standalone solution I'd want ideally, I did realize the Jenkins CLI functionality offers a lot to help.

As directed here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

I downloaded the jenkins-cli.jar and then used this to get my output in my shell session:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <SERVERURL> build <JOBNAME> -s -v
```

The "-s -v" instructs it to wait for completion and display the console output back in my shell